# debugging global variable in eclipse (C/C++)

Tags: c, eclipse

I wrote this sample C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct _sampleStruct{
    int f1;
    double f2;
    int f3[SIZE];
}sampleStruct;

sampleStruct g_s;

int main() {

    sampleStruct s;
    sampleStruct zeroed = {0};
    s.f1 = g_s.f1 = 1;
    s.f2 = g_s.f2 = 2.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        s.f3[i] = g_s.f3[i] = i*10;

    }
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(sampleStruct));
    printf("s: %d, g_s: %lf, zeroed: %d", s.f1, g_s.f2, zeroed.f3[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Eclipse Mars IDE and I want to debug this code. 
the `s` and `zeroed` variables are shown in the variables tab.
however, the `g_s` (which is a global variable) is not shown there. 
is there a way for me to see its fields and how they're changing etc.?

EDIT: just figured out there's a "add global variables" button but it is grayed, so I can't press it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so after some more googling about it I found [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285575) .
tl;dr - the problem was that I was using the default GDB(DSF) process launcher. apparently this is a known issue (more details in the link above).

what you should do to solve it:
go to Run-->Debug Configurations and check at the bottom of the opened window which debug launcher you are using. if it is the GDB(DSF) then press the "Select other..." link below it. In the opened window mark "Use configuration specific settings" and then choose a different launcher (in my case it is "Legacy Create Process Launcher").
now the "add global variables should not be gray and you can click it and choose the variables you want to watch.

leaving the question just in case someone will encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope that you find this visual description helpful.**

---

Click the `Add Global Variables` icon (green dot with eye-glasses above it):

[image]

---

Which is located under the `Variables` tab:

[image]

---

Here is a zoom-out of both:

[image]

Comment: this is god in case the "add global variables" is not grayed. I added an answer about it below.

Comment: @noamgot: It's enabled when you're running and paused, and disabled (grayed out) otherwise. In any case, please tell me if this answer is suitable for Mars IDE, so I can remove it otherwise.

Comment: I just changed again to GDB(DSF), it is grayed before I run a debug session, and also when I get to a breakpoint...