# How can I see global variables when debugging C/C++ code in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I used to be able to see global variables in the Variables view when debugging C/C++ code in Eclipse. Now, I only see local variables, and the "Add Global Variables..." option (the icon was a globe with eyeglasses over it) is gone:

[image]

I can manually add an expression, but this is inconvenient. Am I missing something, or was this removed intentionally?

I'm using Eclipse 2019-12 with Eclipse CDT 9.10.0.201912051559 on Windows 10.

Comment: This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265556/debugging-global-variable-in-eclipse-c-c

Comment: FWIW, you should really avoid global variables if you can.  Constants aren't bad (they can't change) but mutable globals make the code harder to reason about and tend to be the source of bugs.

Comment: @TheRight I did see that question, but as I stated, the "Add Global Variables ..." option is now gone entirely, so that's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables **are not shown** in the **Variables view.**

Instead, you can add the ones you are interested in within the Expressions view.
You can follow this link, it can help you : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=219040

Comment: As I stated in the question, "I can manually add an expression, but this is inconvenient." I'm looking for a way to restore the old behavior where I could see global variables by default.

Comment: @David Please comment on the mentioned bug.